# How to get json array by key into listview by fecth in PDO

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a problem to show my data into listview in android when i using output by PDO SQL ini my php code, I've searching but nothing like my code, I am newbe, please help me.
This my error :

```
6-13 00:51:50.589 21781-21781/com.spp.udi.sppmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: com.spp.udi.sppmap, PID: 21781
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spp.udi.sppmap/com.spp.udi.sppmap.Potensi}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at com.spp.udi.sppmap.Potensi.onCreate(Potensi.java:37)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6323)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1347) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My ListActivity :

```
    package com.spp.udi.sppmap;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Potensi extends ListActivity {
    private Context mContext;

    private static final String ID_KECAMATAN = "id_kecamatan";
    private static final String NAMA_KECAMATAN = "nama_kecamatan";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new fetchDataFromJSON().execute();
    }

    private class fetchDataFromJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Potensi.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson("http://sppmap.esy.es/android/potensi.php");
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("result");
                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject jsonobj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id_kecamatan = jsonobj.getString(ID_KECAMATAN);
                    String nama_kecamatan = jsonobj.getString(NAMA_KECAMATAN);
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("id_kecamatan", id_kecamatan);
                    map.put("nama_kecamatan", nama_kecamatan);
                    mylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.adapter_listview();
        }

        public void adapter_listview() {
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(mContext, mylist, R.layout.potensi,
                    new String[] {ID_KECAMATAN, NAMA_KECAMATAN}, new int[] {R.id.id_kecamatan, R.id.nama_kecamatan});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                    String id_kecamatan = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_kecamatan)).getText().toString();
                    Intent in = new Intent(mContext, DetailPotensi.class);
                    in.putExtra(ID_KECAMATAN, id_kecamatan);
                    startActivity(in);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I hope anybody can help me to fix my problem thank you..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I have edit my activity code.. this is diferrent.

Answer (score 0):

As this line state

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spp.udi.sppmap/com.spp.udi.sppmap.Potensi}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

which mean your JSON return from the URL is null but I assume the HTTP request never even fire. Your code for handling JSON is work perfectly. But in android application there is better to not do a HTTP request in your main thread which will lead to crash instead run it on worker thread or create a asynchronous with `AsyncTask` see this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html). I never try `JSONFunction.getJSONFromUrl` to make a HTTP request before but if im not wrong it is a synchronous request process so better use other library which make a http request asynchronous. Here some good library you can use

1. [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) (A little bit hard to understand at first but indeed very robust)
2. [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) (Recomended)
3. [OK HTTP](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) (i'm using this)

Either of the library having a succesful block which guarantee return a string from your server if the server do return one so on that point you can use to process your output.